# Put a trigger or constraint to check update query must have where clause before updating a table

Tags: mysql, constraints

I want to make trigger or constraint on table. Whenever a update query is fire on table the update query have where clause. If It didn't then discard the update.

Or How we can restrict update query to not allow for updating all column.

I am using mysql database.

Comment: How will this help is I use `WHERE 1=1`?

Comment: Not updating all *columns* has nothing to do with adding a where clause.